# How to program Discord bot with optional multi-word argument?

Tags: python, discord.py

I programmed a Discord bot that would take a command $get_inspiration and return a random poetry quote from Goodreads. I want to update the bot so that it takes an optional multi-word argument, searches the argument on Goodreads quotes, and returns a random quote from the search results. So if someone enters $get_inspiration yeats poetry, it should return the search results of "yeats poetry" on Goodreads quotes, but if nothing is entered, it returns any random quote like it's currently programmed to do.

I've written a custom function get_poem() which is referenced in the code below.

```
async def get_inspiration(ctx, *arg):
    "Returns random poetry quote from Goodreads"
    response = get_poem(" ".join(arg[:]))
    await ctx.send(response)
```

When I've done `async def get_inspiration(ctx, *arg)`, it works perfectly when I've entered a search term, e.g. $get_inspiration yeats poetry, but I want it to be optional such that entering just $get_inspiration returns a random quote. However, when I've tried `async def get_inspiration(ctx, *arg = None)` I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". I also tried `get_inspiration(ctx, *, arg = None)` but that didn't work in the way I expected. If I entered only $get_inspiration, I would get a "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error. If I entered a search word, e.g. $get_inspiration yeats, it would (for some reason) return Spanish quotes exclusively.

What's the proper way to do this? I'm pretty new to Python and also to Discord.py in general. The code for the custom function get_poem, which is referenced above, is quite long so I haven't included it here. If anyone needs to see the code, however, I will be happy to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't in how you are taking input `get_inspiration(ctx, *, arg=None)` is completely fine. However you never check if an input is given and end up trying to index into a `NoneType`.

You can just do a simple check to see if there is any input:

```
if arg:
  response = get_poem(" ".join(arg[:]))
else:
  # code to get random quote

await ctx.send(response)
```

Also if your parameters are `*, arg=None` then `arg` is returned as just one string and not a list. A list is returned if the parameters are `*arg`. The main difference is that the latter accepts multiple inputs as multiple inputs whereas the first one accepts multiple inputs as a single input. You can learn more about it [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters). So you should be able to do just `get_poem(arg)`.

Comment: This is just a little more advanced info but if you use `get_poem(arg)` then you can actually let the `get_poem()` function itself handle the input validation which might make your code a little smoother and more readable. I have done a lot of discord.py so I am happy to help, good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This was super helpful and I appreciate your patience. After changing it to `get_poem(arg)` it worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad I could help, if you get the chance make sure to mark that your question was answered. This helps other people who might have similar questions. Good luck!